# Table not updating in EF when updating with a SQL call?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an issue Im running into with EF and SQL. I have a crazy stored proc that doesnt translate well to C# code (EF/LINQ). Basically, what I do is call the stored proc with a SqlConnection and SqlCommand call (System.Data.SqlClient) [See below] then pull the data from the table using EF. This happens over and over until a main table is depleted. (I have a main table with several hundred thousand records and the stored proc pulls a small portion of that and puts it in a table to be processed, once processed, those records are removed from the main table and it goes all over again until the main table has been completely processed).

The issue is that the table never gets updated in C#, but it IS getting updated on the backend.

So here's the SQL Call:

```
 SqlConnection sqlConn;
   SqlCommand sqlCommand;

   using (sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppMRIConnection"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(String.Format("EXEC sp_PullFinalDataSetPart '{0}', '{1}'", sLocation, sOutputFileType), sqlConn))
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConn.Close();
        }
    }
```

That truncates the FinalDataSetPart table and re-loads it with X new records.

This is the call in C#

```
List<FinalDataSetPart> lstFinalPart = db.FinalDataSetPart.ToList();
```

This call will ALWAYS get the first finaldatasetpart table loaded regardless of what is actually in the table. That call is correctly inside the loop (I can break into the code and see it calling that method every loop iteration).

Has anyone seen anything like this before?!

Any thoughts/help/tips would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest starting up SQL Profiler and doing some monitoring.  It is possible that your EF context only makes the initial call while the subsequent calls simply return objects that are now in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the ID's change in the temporary table when you pull in new data? EF won't detect changes to data if the primary id's don't change.

Do you drop en recreate the context everytime you grab new data?

Comment: Yeah, I had to drop and re-create the context. I guess I was missing that step! Thanks!